# Can't save Arabic text from csv to txt file

Tags: php, json, csv

I have a csv file like this:

```
region_name, city_name, district_name, ppm_value
منطقة, مدينة , حي , 220.92
...
```

All columns are strings in Arabic, except `ppm_value` which is a float number. I'm trying to process the csv file and reproduce it in json format. I tried this:

```
$districts = array();
$fd = fopen('data2.csv', 'r');
while ($row = fgetcsv($fd)) {
    $region = $row[0];
    $city = $row[1];
    $district = new stdClass();
    $district->name = "".$row[2];
    $district->ppm = $row[3];
    //also add region and city to $district

    $districts[] = $district;
}

$json1=json_encode($districts);
file_put_contents("text.txt",$json1);
```

This produces the following:

```
[{"name":null,"ppm":"220.92","region":null,"city":null}, ... ]
```

The float is saved correctly, but the Arabic strings are all null. I even tried to save it like this but I got the same result:

```
$myfile = fopen('text.txt', "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, json_encode($districts));    
fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know next to nothing about php, but perhaps the problem is that your arabic text is being encoded as ASCII?

try changing it to unicode before you add it to you JSON object, you probably know how to do this better than I do...

```
string utf8_encode ( string $data )
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks!